# PHP jQuery AJAX post not posting data in mobile mode

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I write the code in CodeIgniter to post the data to post data with multiple file uploader. It's working on the web browser. But in mobile devices, my code is not working

The data is passed in the formData. I inspect it in mobile all the post data variables are blank. But in desktop its show me all the variable

Here is jQuery AJAX post code

```
var form_data = new FormData($("#form-upload")[0]);
 // all data append in this form data
$.ajax({

        url: 'API_Create/ExpenseReport',

        type: "post",

        dataType: 'json',

       processData: false,

        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        data: form_data, 
        success: function(data) {

            data = $.parseJSON(data);

            if (data == true) {

                toastr.success('Expense Report Created.!');

                $('#dateexpense').val();

                $('#expensename').val();

                $('#expensebranch').val('');

                $('#expenseworkorder').val('');

                $('#expensefuel').val('');

                $('#foodallowance').val('');

                $('#expenseticket').val();

                $('#roomallowance').val();

                $('#localtransport').val('');

                $('#tolltax').val('');

                $('#angelfabricate').val('');

                $('#materialpurchase').val('');

                $('#telephone').val('');

                $('#otherexpensesdetails').val('');

                $('#spinwait').hide();

                //location.href = '/AdminList';

            } else if (data == '-1') {

                toastr.success('Expense Report Created.!');
                 $('#spinwait').hide();

            } else {

               toastr.success('Expense Report Created.!');
                 $('#spinwait').hide();

            }

            $.each(data, function(k, v) {});

        },

        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              toastr.error('Expense Report Created.!');
                 $('#spinwait').hide();
            }

    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="mainbar"> 



 <!-- Page heading -->



 <div class="page-head"> 



  <!-- Page heading -->



  <h2 class="pull-left">Expense Report 



   <!-- page meta --> 



   <!--<span class="page-meta">Fields with * are mandatory</span>--> </h2>



  <!-- Breadcrumb -->



  <div class="bread-crumb pull-right"> <a href="/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a> 



   <!-- Divider --> 



   <span class="divider">/</span> <a href="#" class="bread-current">Forms</a> </div>

  <div class="clearfix"></div>

 </div>



 <!--/ Page heading ends --> 



 <!-- Matter -->



 <div class="matter">

  <div class="container">

   <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12">

     <div class="widget wgreen">

      <div class="widget-head">

       <div class="pull-left">Expense Information </div>

       <div class="widget-icons pull-right"> </div>

       <div class="clearfix"></div>

      </div>

      <div class="widget-content">

       <div class="padd"> 



        <!-- Form starts.  -->



        <form class="form-horizontal" id="form-upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"/>



        <div class="col-md-10">

         <div class="form-group">

          <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Work Order No. / काम संख्या </label>

          <div class="col-md-9">

           <select class="form-control" id="expenseworkorder">

            <option>--Select Work Order</option>

           </select>

           <!--           <p id="lblexpenseworkorder" style="color:red; font-weight:bold; display:none;">Please enter Work Order No.</p>

--> </div>

         </div>

         <div class="form-group">

          <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Date / तिथि </label>

          <div class="col-md-9">

           <input type="text" class="form-control eee"   id="dateexpense"/>

           <!--           <p id="lbldateexpense" style="color:red; font-weight:bold; display:none;">Please Choose Date</p>

--> </div>

         </div>

         <div class="form-group">

          <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Name / नाम </label>

          <div class="col-md-9">

           <select class="form-control" id="expensename">

           </select>

           <!-- <p id="lblexpensename" style="color:red; font-weight:bold; display:none;">Please enter username</p>--> </div>

         </div>

         <div class="form-group">

          <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Branch / शाखा </label>

          <div class="col-md-9">

           <input type="text" class="form-control eee"  id="expensebranch"/>

          </div>

         </div>

         <div class="form-group expen">

          <label class="col-md-12 control-label">

          <h1 style="color:#000; text-align:center;"><b>Expense Details</b></h1>

          </label>

         </div>

         <div class="form-group">

          <label class="col-md-3 control-label"> </label>

          <div class="col-md-2">

           <label class="control-label"> Amount</label>

          </div>

          <div class="col-md-2">

           <label class="control-label"> Description</label>

          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4"> </div>

         </div>



         <div class="form-group">

          <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Fuel / ईंधन</label>

          <div class="col-md-2">

           <input type="text" class="form-control eee"  id="expensefuel"/>

           <!--           <p id="lblexpensefuel" style="color:red; font-weight:bold; display:none;">Please enter Expense Details</p>

--> </div>

          <div class="col-md-2">

           <input type="text" class="form-control eee"  id="expensefuel1"/>

           <p id="lblexpensefuel1" style="color:red; font-weight:bold; display:none;">Please enter Expense Details</p>

          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">

           <div  id="uploadContainer">

            <input type="file" name="fuelfile[]" id="fuelfile0" class="inputfile inputfile-1" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple="" style="border: transparent !important;" accept="image/*" capture="camera">

           </div>

           <input type ="button" id='extraUpload' value="Add another file" class="btn btn-default btn-md">

          </div>

         </div>

         <div class="form-group">

          <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Food Allowance / भोजन भत्ता</label>

          <div class="col-md-2">

           <input type="text" class="form-control eee"   id="foodallowance"/>

           <!--           <p id="lblfoodallowance" style="color:red; font-weight:bold; display:none;">Please enter Food Allowance</p>

--> </div>

          <div class="col-md-2">

           <input type="text" class="form-control eee"  id="expensefuel2"/>

           <p id="lblexpensefuel2" style="color:red; font-weight:bold; display:none;">Please enter Expense Details</p>

          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">

          <div  id="uploadContainerfood">

           <input type="file" name="foodallowance[]" id="foodallowancefiles0" class="inputfile inputfile-1" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple="" style="border: transparent !important;" accept="image/*" capture="camera">

           </div>

            <input type ="button" id='extraUploadfood' value="Add another file" class="btn btn-default btn-md">

        </div>

         </div>

         <div class="form-group">



          <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Bus/Train Tickets / बस/रेल टिकट </label>

          <div class="col-md-2">

           <input type="text" class="form-control eee"   id="expenseticket"/>

             </div>

          <div class="col-md-2">

           <input type="text" class="form-control eee"  id="expensefuel3"/>

           <!--           <p id="lblexpensefuel3" style="color:red; font-weight:bold; display:none;">Please enter Expense Details</p>

--> </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">

          <div  id="uploadContainerbus">

           <input type="file" name="bus[]" id="bus0" class="inputfile inputfile-1" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple="" style="border: transparent !important;" accept="image/*" capture="camera">

            </div>

             <input type ="button" id='extraUploadbus' value="Add another file" class="btn btn-default btn-md">

  </div>

         </div>

         <div class="form-group">

          <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Room Allowance / कमरा भत्ता</label>

          <div class="col-md-2">

           <input type="text" class="form-control eee"   id="roomallowance"/>

           <!--           <p id="lblroomallowance" style="color:red; font-weight:bold; display:none;">Please enter Room Allowance</p>

--> </div>

          <div class="col-md-2">

           <input type="text" class="form-control eee"  id="expensefuel4"/>

           <!--           <p id="lblexpensefuel4" style="color:red; font-weight:bold; display:none;">Please enter Expense Details</p>

--> </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">

            <div  id="uploadContainerroom">

           <input type="file" name="roomallow[]" id="roomallow0" class="inputfile inputfile-1" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple="" style="border: transparent !important;" accept="image/*" capture="camera">

           </div>

            <input type ="button" id='extraUploadroom' value="Add another file" class="btn btn-default btn-md">

           </div>

         </div>

         <div class="form-group">

          <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Local Transportation / स्थानीय परिवहन</label>

          <div class="col-md-2">

           <input type="text" class="form-control eee"   id="localtransport"/>

           <!--           <p id="lbllocaltransport" style="color:red; font-weight:bold; display:none;">Please Enter Local Transportation</p>

--> </div>

          <div class="col-md-2">

           <input type="text" class="form-control eee"  id="expensefuel5"/>

           <p id="lblexpensefuel5" style="color:red; font-weight:bold; display:none;">Please enter Expense Details</p>

          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">

            <div  id="uploadContainerlocal">

           <input type="file" name="local[]" id="local0" class="inputfile inputfile-1" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple="" style="border: transparent !important;" accept="image/*" capture="camera">

           </div>

             <input type ="button" id='extraUploadlocal' value="Add another file" class="btn btn-default btn-md">

           </div>

         </div>

         <div class="form-group">

          <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Toll Tax / टोल टैक्स</label>

          <div class="col-md-2">

           <input type="text" class="form-control eee"   id="tolltax"/>

           <p id="lbltolltax" style="color:red; font-weight:bold; display:none;">Please enter Toll Tax</p>

          </div>

          <div class="col-md-2">

           <input type="text" class="form-control eee"  id="expensefuel6"/>

           <!--           <p id="lblexpensefuel6" style="color:red; font-weight:bold; display:none;">Please enter Expense Details</p>

--> </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">

          <div  id="uploadContainertoll">

           <input type="file" name="toll[]" id="toll0" class="inputfile inputfile-1" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple="" style="border: transparent !important;" accept="image/*" capture="camera">

           </div>

                     <input type ="button" id='extraUploadtoll' value="Add another file" class="btn btn-default btn-md">



             </div>

         </div>

         <div class="form-group">

          <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Angle/Fabrication / कोण/छलरचना</label>

          <div class="col-md-2">

           <input type="text" class="form-control eee"   id="angelfabricate"/>

           <!--           <p id="lblangelfabricate" style="color:red; font-weight:bold; display:none;">Please enter Angle/Fabrication</p>

--> </div>

          <div class="col-md-2">

           <input type="text" class="form-control eee"  id="expensefuel7"/>

           <p id="lblexpensefuel7" style="color:red; font-weight:bold; display:none;">Please enter Expense Details</p>

          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">

          <div  id="uploadContainerangel">

           <input type="file" name="angle[]" id="angle0" class="inputfile inputfile-1" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple="" style="border: transparent !important;" accept="image/*" capture="camera">

           </div>

        <input type ="button" id='extraUploadangel' value="Add another file" class="btn btn-default btn-md">    

          </div>

         </div>

         <div class="form-group">

          <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Material Purchase / खरीद सामग्री</label>

          <div class="col-md-2">

           <input type="text" class="form-control eee"   id="materialpurchase"/>

           <!--           <p id="lblmaterialpurchase" style="color:red; font-weight:bold; display:none;">Please enter Material Purchase</p>

--> </div>

          <div class="col-md-2">

           <input type="text" class="form-control eee"  id="expensefuel8"/>

           <p id="lblexpensefuel8" style="color:red; font-weight:bold; display:none;">Please enter Expense Details</p>

          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">

          <div  id="uploadContainermaterial">

           <input type="file" name="material[]" id="material0" class="inputfile inputfile-1" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple="" style="border: transparent !important;" accept="image/*" capture="camera">

           </div>

          <input type ="button" id='extraUploadmaterial' value="Add another file" class="btn btn-default btn-md">  

            </div>

         </div>

         <div class="form-group">

          <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Telephone / टेलीफोन</label>

          <div class="col-md-2">

           <input type="text" class="form-control eee"   id="telephone"/>

           <p id="lbltelephone" style="color:red; font-weight:bold; display:none;">Please enter Telephone</p>

          </div>

          <div class="col-md-2">

           <input type="text" class="form-control eee"  id="expensefuel9"/>

           <p id="lblexpensefuel9" style="color:red; font-weight:bold; display:none;">Please enter Expense Details</p>

          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">

          <div  id="uploadContainertelephone">

           <input type="file" name="telephone[]" id="telephonefiles0" class="inputfile inputfile-1" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple="" style="border: transparent !important;" accept="image/*" capture="camera">

           </div>

           <input type ="button" id='extraUploadtelephone' value="Add another file" class="btn btn-default btn-md">

           </div>

         </div>

         <div class="form-group">

          <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Other Expense Details / अन्य विस्तार</label>

          <div class="col-md-2">

           <input type="text" class="form-control eee"   id="otherexpensesdetails"/>

           <p id="lblotherexpensesdetails" style="color:red; font-weight:bold; display:none;">Please enter Other Expense Details</p>

          </div>

          <div class="col-md-2">

           <input type="text" class="form-control eee"  id="expensefuel10"/>

           <!--           <p id="lblexpensefuel10" style="color:red; font-weight:bold; display:none;">Please enter Expense Details</p>

--> </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">

          <div  id="uploadContaineroth">

           <input type="file" name="file-1[]" id="file-10" class="inputfile inputfile-1" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple="" style="border: transparent !important;" accept="image/*" capture="camera">

           </div>

           <input type ="button" id='extraUploadoth' value="Add another file" class="btn btn-default btn-md">

            </div>

         </div>

         <div class="form-group">

          <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Total</label>

          <div class="col-md-2">

           <input type="text" class="form-control eee"   id="totals" disabled="disabled"/>

          </div>

          <div class="col-md-2"> </div>

          <div class="col-md-4"> > </div>

         </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

         <div class="col-md-8">

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default aa" id="btn_submitexpense"><b>Submit</b></button>

          <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/spin.gif" height="55px;" id="spinwait"/> </div>

        </div>

        </form>

       </div>

      </div>

     </div>

    </div>

   </div>

  </div>

 </div>



 <!--/ Matter ends --> 



</div>
```

When I ever I upload more than one file from the mobile then all the variables in the formdata show me blank in a console but working good in the desktop browser...

I stuck in this situation from last 2 days any help is appreciated

Comment: When you are stuck with this for 2 days, I think that you have a lot of stuff that you've tried already. Can you explain us what you did?

Comment: could you share your Html code.

Comment: @KoenHollander I try to separate the uploading code and insert code. I try to change the variable  names for not conflict and also try upload single file for each upload one by one. when I upload one file then there is no issue with multiple uploaders its create issue

Comment: @kmgkumar html added

Comment: it's working fine for me

Comment: @kmgkumar  in mobile?

Comment: what you did can you show me please? @kmgkumar